# Why are letters dissapearing when document is sent to the printer. MTPRO2

Tags: fonts, printing, mtpro

Whenever I send pdf-documents typeset with MTPRO2 (it only happens for MTPRO2) to be printed, certain combination of letters will disappear from the print, so far, I have only found that this happens to double fs. For instance, if the word `differential` was contained in a document sent to the printer, the printer will print `di  erential`, with a double white-space where the two fs are. This happens on about half the printers I have tried on the campus.

Why does this happen?

Comment: It will likely happen also for `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, `ffl`. The printer doesn't print the ligatures. Are you should you have the fonts properly installed? Do you print from a PDF file? What fonts does the file include (can be found in properties of the file somewhere)?

Comment: Some printers have configurable options on the font.  For example, in the advanced-tab settings for my HP Color LaserJet 3800, I have two ways to handle TrueType fonts: "Substitute with Device Font" or "Download as Soft Font".  Another is "Send TrueType as Bitmap" which can be selected as "enabled" or "disabled."  I have found that changing such printer configurations can often fix the type of problem you describe.

Comment: The `mtpro2` package does only math-mode material. Are you writing the word "differential" in math mode, i.e., as `$... differential ...$`? Ligatures should not be used in math material. Consider writing `$... \textit{differential} ...$` instead.

Comment: @yo' Yes you are correct. All of ligatures are missing. When I send the PDF document to be printed from a different computer, then everything works correctly. What do you reckon? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem seems to be dependent on printer drivers and is not reproducible